# manipulating ng-model value in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to manipulate the value of ng-model in ionic. It works fine in name attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="svData.q{{option.qoQID}}" value="{{option.qoID}}">
```

the output was right as expected:

```
<input type="radio" name="svData.q1" value="1">
```

I'm trying to use ng-model attribute instead of name. I've tried:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="svData.q{{option.qoQID}}" value="{{option.qoID}}">
```

and it does not work.

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token

was produced. 
I was expecting the output to be like:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="svData.q1" value="1">
```

any solution or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ngModel directive will only bind the `value` attribute of the input to a property on the scope. If you intend to bind the `name` attribute then you will have to use the ngBind syntax `{{ }}` the way you did in the beginning